# django permission error /admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, wagtail

I get permission error. Permission denied for /admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff on my docker container.  I got this error by getting inside the docker container by the command docker exec -it container /bin/bash and running curl -XGET 'http://localhost'  It is displaying error on the line  {% stylesheet 'style' %} on my base.html.    The docker is inside ubuntu machine which is on aws.  I am running this application with nginx and uwsgi.  uid and gid in uwsgi .ini is www-data. Please help me in fixing this issue.

Please find docker logs

```
root@ip-10-252-14-11:/home/ubuntu/workarea/sourcecode/ntdl/ntdl# docker logs 
ntdl

> ntdl@1.0.2 start-prod /home/ntdl/code
> concurrently --no-color "uwsgi --ini /home/ntdl/code/uwsgi.ini" "nginx" 
 "npm run render-prod"

[0] [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /home/ntdl/code/uwsgi.ini
[2]
[2] > ntdl@1.0.2 render-prod /home/ntdl/code
[2] > babel-node node/react-render.jsx
[2]
[2] React render server listening at http://0.0.0.0:9009
[2] *****  app. post
[2] Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated, 
and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.* prop- 
types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility, migration 
and more, see 
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] global ntdl - react render - url http://54.252.92.17/api/search
[2] AJAX Failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.252.92.17:80
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] *****  app. post
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] global ntdl - react render - url http://54.252.92.17/api/search
[2] AJAX Failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.252.92.17:80
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] *****  app. post
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []  
[2] global ntdl - react render - url http://54.252.92.17/api/search
[2] AJAX Failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.252.92.17:80
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] *****  app. post
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props [] 
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] global ntdl - react render - url http://54.252.92.17/api/search
[2] AJAX Failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.252.92.17:80
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] *****  app. post
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets [] 
[2] global ntdl - react render - url http://54.252.92.17/api/search
[2] AJAX Failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.252.92.17:80
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] *****  app. post
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
[2] global ntdl - react render - url http://54.252.92.17/api/search
[2] AJAX Failed: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.252.92.17:80
[2] advancedFacets - constructor - props []
[2] _updateProps []
[2] render advanced Facets - facets []
```

hi Gasman, you can see the permission error Actually the roboto font file is available at that path.  Secondly it throwing error at {% stylesheet 'style' %}
Please tell me what would be the problem.

[image]

With many thanks,
Bharath AK

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're (presumably) hosting the font on Amazon S3. When loading fonts from remote domains, current browsers require valid [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) HTTP headers.

If you're using the `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage` backend, you can add the appropriate headers by adding the following lines to your settings file:

```
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
```

and re-running `./manage.py collectstatic`. See http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/advanced_topics/deploying.html#cloud-storage for further details.

Comment: Hi Gasman I had made the changes as you said in setting.py Still I get the same error.  Please guide me  what can be done.  I am not able to attach the curl output it is big  Please suggest how to attach the curl output .html so that you can have an idea  With Many thanks, Bharath AK

Comment: Hi mate.  I had added the docker logs above on the question for more details  but I haven't attached the curl output since it is too big.  Please help me in resolving this.  With Many thanks bharath AK

Comment: when I run root@fb9955d98b4d:/home/ntdl/code# ss -tlp 'sport = 80'  I get the following results as follows
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                     Local Address:Port                                                      Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128                                                    *:http                                                                 *:*                     users:(("nginx",pid=27,fd=6))   But for ajax call connection refused you can see from the docker logs above

Comment: there is EXPOSE 80 in the Dockerfile. port 80 is exposed.

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. If AJAX and font requests are failing, the problem is almost certainly that you're requesting them from a remote domain, and need to return the appropriate HTTP headers. It's nothing to do with your port configuration.

Comment: I had included these line AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
} and tested it after doing collectstatic. still I get the same error.   What I have to do to fix this issue.

Comment: I am calling curl -XGET 'http://localhost' from inside docker.  All files are inside docker and ajax call fails inside docker.  Will it be cors issue.  I am not calling from outside

Comment: Roboto-regular web font is inside docker. File actually exists inside the docker.   it is not referencing outside.

Comment: I had added the screenshot for the permission error throwing at {% stylesheet 'style' %}  Please tell me what can be done.  With Many thanks Bharath

Comment: Man,https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/, as they say you have to change your `CORS` permissions in `AWS`, and instead to put `*`, put your domain url.

Answer (score 0):

My issue occurred after rebuilding docker images with my Django application and the problem was in the lack of permissions to file `/vol/web/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff`.
Finally it was lack of the permissions to whole Docker's named volume folder:

```
services:
    my_app:
        volumes:
            static_data:/vol/web
...

volumes:
    static_data:
```

I've finally managed to make it working by removing the content of the volume's mount directory (previously **doing a backup** of it, which in my case was located here: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my_app_static_data/_data/`) and allowing Docker to recreate this volume.
I don't know how it happened, but my whole volume directory was owned by some weird `opc` user and group, not my regular user.

Probably running simple:

```
sudo chown my_user:my_user /var/lib/docker/volumes/my_app_static_data/_data
```

would do the job as well.